# Show $(\text{ker}(\phi))a=(\text{ker}(\phi))b$ if and only if $a^6 = b^6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a commutative group that is written multiplicatively.
Define $\phi:G \rightarrow G$ by $\phi(g)=g^6$.

We already showed $\phi$ is a group homomorphism and that $\ker(\phi)$ is any element $g$ in $G$ with order dividing $6$.

Show $(\ker(\phi))a = (\ker(\phi))b$ if and only if $a^6 = b^6$

Comment: What is a and b?

Comment: What does $(\ker(\phi))a$ mean?

Comment: As usual, for any subgroup of a group, $Ha=Hb$ if and only if $ab^{-1}\in H$. So check that.

Comment: @Cornman i forgot part of the question, i'm sorry!

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if $\phi : G \to G'$ is a group homomorphism with kernel $K$, then $Ka = \phi^{-1}(\phi(a))$ and so $Ka=Kb$ iff $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$ because $\phi(Ka)=\{\phi(a)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

By G is commutative,
\begin{align}
a^6=b^6&\Leftrightarrow (ab^{-1})^6=1\\
&\Leftrightarrow ab^{-1}\in\ker\phi
\end{align}

Comment: You don’t need commutativity for this; you need commutativity for $\phi$ to be a homomorphism, but with any homomorphism, two elements are congruent modulo the kernel if and only if they have the same image. $\phi(a)=a^6=b^6=\phi(b)$, so $\phi(ab^{-1})=\phi(a)\phi(b)^{-1}=1$.

Comment: Certainly. That's right.